# Summing all primes in a number: 9 returns true

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I am currently stuck with this challenge: https://www.freecodecamp.org/challenges/sum-all-primes

I am trying to sum all the prime numbers from 0 to 10

I have a function to check if the number is a prime number. If I pass 9 it returns false which is good.

However when I am decrementing from 10 with a while loop and it passes 9 into the function it seems to be returning true and adding it to my sum. As a result I get the result of 24 when the sum of all the prime numbers in 10 is 17! This is because it is adding 9 as a prime number.

Here is my code, I must be missing something obviouse here but I can figure it out!

```js
function sumPrimes(num) {
  function isPrime() {
    for (var i = 2; i <= num; i++) {
      if (num % i === 0) {
        return false;
      }
      return num !== 1;
    }
  }
  // alert(isPrime(9)); // returns false
  var count = 0;
  while (num >= 0) {
    if (isPrime(num)) {
      count += num;
      console.log(count);
    }
    num--;
  }
  console.log(count);
}

sumPrimes(10);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you need to return true from `isPrime()` if no number less than num divides the number so remove `return num !== 1;` from inside the for loop and add `return true` after the loop. Also you are running the loop in function `isPrime()` till the number num, since every number is divisible by itself, function will return false for every number, change for loop condition to `i<num`. Also note that 1 is not a prime number so you don't need to add it in the sum.

```js
function sumPrimes(num) {
function isPrime(num){
    if(num === 1 ) //since 1 is neither prime nor composite.
       return false;
    for (var i = 2; i < num; i++) {
        if (num % i === 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
// alert(isPrime(9)); // returns false
var count = 0;
while (num >= 0) {
    if (isPrime(num)) {
        count += num;
        alert(count);
    }
    num--;
}
console.log(count);
}

sumPrimes(10);
```

Comment: The original code DOESN'T return false for every number (his code really does return 24 and not 0) - because there's another error in the original definition of isPrime.  It only checks for i === 2, since the `return num !== 1;` is also inside the for loop in the original version.

Answer (score 1):

try to modify the following code snippet

```
function isPrime() {
    for (var i = 2; i <= Math.sqrt(num); i++) {
      if (num % i === 0) {return false;}
    }
    return true;
  }
```

Using `Math.sqrt(num)` as an upper limit will improve time complexity and speed up the computation for large numbers (see my online Prime Numbers Calculator up to 18 digits implementing this algo with some additional optimization: http://examn8.com/Primes.aspx )

Hope this may help.

Comment: because of i <= num it will always return false

Comment: Thanks for your comment: the right way is to use Math.sqrt(num) as an upper limit, it will dramatically improve the time complexity, very important for the large numbers. Regards,